# Cycle through and separate CSV data into secondary array depending on value

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I am developing an online tool to display information in an organized dashboard interface.
I am pulling the data from a CSV spreadsheet and separating them into another multiD array depending on one field in the overall CSV data array.

**This is what I have tried:**

```
        // arr is the array that holds the entire CSV data
        // inds is where I need the entries separated by industry (arr[i][0])
        var indx = 0; // using to add new array to inds array
        for(var i = 1; i < arr.length-1; i++){ 
            if(arr[i][0] === arr[i-1][0]) {
                if(! inds[indx] ) {
                    inds[indx] = []
                } else {
                    inds[indx].push(arr[i]);
                }
            } else {
                indx++;
            }
        }
```

**Basically what this does:**
If the industry field is the same as the entry before, throw it into the arr array with the index of `indx`, otherwise, add one to the `indx` for the next industry.

**The problem with this solution:**
It skips the 1st entry of the industry, because the row before was a different industry, so the `arr[i-1][0]` is checking the last industry and skips the 1st row of the next industry.

**How can I reformat this script:**
I was thinking maybe nested for/while, but not sure. The way I am thinking of the logic is:
For each row of the csv, while industry column is the same, toss into respective `inds[index]`. Or, extract rows from arr by the same value of `arr[i][0]`.

I am sure there is an easier solution, and that is why I am here, so I hope I got my thoughts across clearly and I appreciate any and all feedback.

If you need more clarification, just let me know in the comments.

Comment: There are no "multiD array"s in these languages; you can only nest arrays (strictly speaking, an element of an array can be a reference to another Array instance), which is a different thing. It is unclear to me from your description what the code is *intended to do*. Please provide an example of the expected input and output data so that solutions to the problem can be suggested instead of fixes to your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does the following logic work?

```
var indx = -1;
 // using to add new array to inds array
        for(var i = 1; i < arr.length-1; i++){ 
            if(arr[i][0] !== arr[i-1][0]) {
                indx++;
                inds[indx] = []
            }
            inds[indx].push(arr[i]);
        }
```

Updated.

Comment: (and start with indx = -1 instead of 0;)

Comment: that did work a bit better. but it is still skipping the very 1st instance of the industry in the field `arr[i][0]`

Comment: oooo.. that console.log was sexy! perfect! thank you so much! been banging my head on my desk trying to get this to work correctly.